# NSExtensionItem attachments array, can it be sorted by order in which user picks photos in iPhone Photos app?

Tags: ios, share-extension

NSExtensionItem attachments array, can it be sorted by order in which user picks photos in iPhone Photos app?

I'm developing an iOS app which has share extension by which user can share photos through iPhone Photos app to my app.

However, one user said that he would like the order in which he selected the photos to be maintained when sharing the photos on my app.

Looking at the `attachments` property of `NSExtensionItem`, the photos were arranged in the order of the photos in the photo app, not in the order in which the user selected them.

I think app developers should be able to maintain the order in which users select photos if they want, but is there such a way?